# Unable to catch error in react version 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs

Unable to catch errors In React 18.2.0 version

I have Written an ErrorBoundary like this.

```
const FallBackComponents = () => {
   console.log('Fall Back Component')
   return <h1>FallBack COmppnent</h1>
}

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<any, any> {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null }
   }

   componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
      this.setState({
         error: error,
         errorInfo: errorInfo
      })
      // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
   }

   render() {
      if (this.state.errorInfo) {
         // Error path
         return <FallBackComponents />
      }
      // Normally, just render children
      return this.props.children
   }
}
```

and in my code I have wrapped my component  with this ErrorBoundary like this.

```
    <ErrorBoundary>
       <DummyComponent />
       </ErrorBoundary>
```

In the DummyComponent im just throwing the error like

```
Function DummyComponent=()=>{
     throw Error("Somethingwent wrong")
    return <h1>Dummy Component</h1>
}
```

But im not getting my fall back component , instead getting only the Error screeen. Can anyone help me to getout of this.

Comment: A `throw` will raise the `Error` raised and will not continue the next steps, if `DummyComponent` is inside `ErrorBoundary`, I don't think you need the `throw` at all, since something else already *threw* the error. (ES-Lint gives me a warning when I copy the code into my VSCode window)